# Run an interactive Dos program from java

Tags: java, multithreading, dos

I would like to run a Dos program from a web server. The Dos program has to be run interactively as the user interface is via a series of questions and answers. The answer to one question will determine the next question. I will have to use ajax on the web server, but I think I can do that.

I found one java program on Stackoverflow which seems to do something similar to what I want. However when I compile the program I get an error ie.

```
javac PipeRedirection.java 
PipeRedirection.java:43: package InputProcess does not exist
                    InputProcess.Gobbler outGobbler = new InputProcess.Gobbler(p.getInputStream());
```

The stack overflow question url was

[How can I write large output to Process getOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068713/how-can-i-write-large-output-to-process-getoutputstream)

The Java file was

```
/* 
 ####### PipeRedirection.java 
*/

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PipeRedirection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    if(args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Need at least two arguments");
            System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
            String input = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

                    String[] commandList = args[i].split(" ");

                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
                    //pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
                    Process p = pb.start();

                    if(input != null) {
                            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(p.getOutputStream())), true);
                            writer.println(input);
                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();
                    }

                    InputProcess.Gobbler outGobbler = new InputProcess.Gobbler(p.getInputStream());
                    InputProcess.Gobbler errGobbler = new InputProcess.Gobbler(p.getErrorStream());
                    Thread outThread = new Thread(outGobbler);
                    Thread errThread = new Thread(errGobbler);
                    outThread.start();
                    errThread.start();

                    outThread.join();
                    errThread.join();

                    int exitVal = p.waitFor();
                    System.out.println("\n****************************");
                    System.out.println("Command: " + args[i]);
                    System.out.println("Exit Value = " + exitVal);
                    List<String> output = outGobbler.getOuput();
                    input = "";
                    for(String o: output) {
                            input += o;
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("Final Output:");
            System.out.println(input);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println(ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println(ie.getLocalizedMessage());
            ie.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static class Gobbler implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private List<String> output;

    public Gobbler(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    }

    public void run() {
            String line;
            this.output = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                    while((line = this.reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            this.output.add(line + "\n");
                    }
                    this.reader.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO
                    System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            }
    }

    public List<String> getOuput() {
            return this.output;
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone know why I get the compile error? Can I substitute some other code for InputProcess?

Thanks for any help

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's pretty obvious that you're missing parts to this code. A package named `InputProcess` which has a class called `Gobbler` was not included in the OP's post. Probably because it was not relevant to their question.

The error message essentially says that it can not find this package/code that it is looking for.

What this class does exactly, only the OP can tell you. At its most basic, though, it appears to read from an `InputStream` and convert it to a `List<String>`. I would read up on Java IO and try to replicate similar functionality.

Edit:

Looks like the `Gobbler` class is indeed included in the example above. Remove the `InputProcess` package name from your code (or put the `Gobbler` class in an `InputProcess` package) and you should be good to go.

Comment: I read your comment and then I realized that Gobbler is defined above. I just deleted "InputProcess." from the above code and now it compiles and runs fine. Thanks for triggering an answer. Cheers